# The Puzzle of Puzzles - Pieces of Logic

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

[image: Good Luck]

**The Story**

Johnny has added several new jigsaw puzzles to his somewhat large, and unusual collection this year. He likes Computer related puzzles, and the outdoors, as well. Your job, Determine each puzzle's size (number of pieces), theme, issuing company.

**Your 5 Clues**

1. The puzzle with the postage stamp theme has 500 more pieces than the jigsaw puzzle made by Texas Instruments.
2. The puzzle with the website theme has 250 more pieces than the puzzle made by StackExchange.
3. The jigsaw puzzle with the website theme is either the jigsaw puzzle with 750 pieces or the puzzle made by Texas Instruments.
4. The jigsaw puzzle made by Radio Shack has somewhat more than the jigsaw puzzle with the city skyline theme.
5. Of the jigsaw puzzle with the outer space theme and the jigsaw puzzle with the postage stamp theme, one has 250 pieces and the other was made by Radio Shack.

**Puzzle Data:**
StackExchange , AOL, Radio Shack, Texas Instruments, Outer Space, City Skyline, Website, Postage Stamp, 250, 500, 750, 1000

**Hint:** Puzzle Grid

> You will have to research my other puzzles for that link.

**Hint:** Blank Answer Grid

> Sorry, not this time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1   The puzzle with the postage stamp theme has 500 more pieces than the jigsaw puzzle made by Texas Instruments.
```

> Postage stamp theme either 750 or 1000 pieces; TI has either 250 or 500 pieces.

```
2   The puzzle with the website theme has 250 more pieces than the puzzle made by StackExchange.
```

> If TI has 250 pieces, then SE has to have 750 pieces and so website has 1000 pieces. If TI has 500 pieces, TI has website themes and SE has 250 pieces.

```
3   The jigsaw puzzle with the website theme is either the jigsaw puzzle with 750 pieces or the puzzle made by Texas Instruments.
```

> In either case above, website can’t have 750 pieces. Therefore TI has website theme, and so TI - 500 pieces - website theme is locked in. Then SE has 250 pieces and postage stamp has 1000 pieces.

```
4   The jigsaw puzzle made by Radio Shack has somewhat more than the jigsaw puzzle with the city skyline theme.
```

> See below.

```
5   Of the jigsaw puzzle with the outer space theme and the jigsaw puzzle with the postage stamp theme, one has 250 pieces and the other was made by Radio Shack.
```

> Postage stamp must be made by RS because it doesn’t have 250 pieces. So: RS - 1000 pieces - postage stamp theme is locked in. SE - 250 pieces - outer space theme is locked in. Then by elimination, AOL - 750 pieces - city skyline theme is locked in.

Therefore:

> Radio Shack - 1000 pieces - postage stamp 
>  AOL - 750 pieces - city skyline 
>  Texas Instruments - 500 pieces - website 
>  Stack Exchange - 250 pieces - outer space.